# An strange , spontaneous edit done to a question

Tags: support, bug, editing

I asked [a question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12305/complexity-of-an-algorithm-for-bounding-a-region-in-2d) that was a bit hard to explain , so I had to edit it with every comment on it.

I noticed that in one of my edits (edit #13), I have somehow reverted all of the previous edits. If you have ever edited at Wikipedia ,I mean something like editing an old version of an article happened.(I added something but deleted all changes added after some version of the question). You can see this in the [revision history of the question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/12305/revisions).(edit number 13, and I modified it in edit number 14 using [provided source](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/711b5523-4be7-4071-81d0-8a7e69cff4e9/view-source) of each version).

But I didn't remove anything from the question in that edit (#13), just added a single sentence at the end of it.

I wonder how can it have happened; and also, is there any straightforward way to revert an edit?

Comment: It looks like you did edit from an older versions. Maybe developers can know more about what happened by looking at server logs. Please edit the question once more to make it read like you want it to read. You can't remove an edit, all you can do is edit again to what happens to be an old version (there's a button for that in the revision history: rollback).

Comment: I've un-community-wikied the question, but please try not to make too many edits, try to make all the improvements you can think of in one go.

Comment: I just clicked on the edit button at the end the question. Also, The rollback button is not available for the current version of the post.

Comment: It seems you fixed the problem for now. You can tell that your question was not ready for Stack Exchange yet: you should have discussed it with peers offline, or in chat, in order to mold it into clear enough shape. That is not only an act of courtesy towards the users here, but also increases your chances of receiving an answer (few will follow an initially bad question to the end).